# Generating a string (for filename) without space

Tags: expansion

My situation is this. I have a string in some macro definition which is to be used as a file name. Before I create the file, I want to remove all the spaces from that name. I tried something like this following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\def\namewithspaces{A Name With Space}

\newtoks\tempstring
\def\createfilewithoutspaceinname#1{\tempstring=\expandafter{\StrDel{#1}{ }.lst}
  \typeout{\the\tempstring}
  \newwrite\fl
  \openout\fl=\the\tempstring}

\begin{document}

\createfilewithoutspaceinname{\namewithspaces}

\end{document}
```

I expected the file name to be something like, `ANameWithSpace.lst`, but in reality this is not happening.

As can be seen from the added `\typeout` command, the value of `\tempstring` is,

```
\let \@xs@assign \@xs@expand@and@assign \@xs@StrSubstitute@ {\namewithspaces }{ }{}.lst
```

Looks like I am missing something of the expansion.

Comment: I don't think that `\StrDel` is expandable at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the `\tempstring` should be a macro which is used as the last optional argument of `\StrDel` and this macro should be fed to `\openout\tl`.

I also recommend not to use a `\newwrite` each time `\createfilenamewithspaceinname` is applied (unless the file is closed etc. or in a group)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\def\namewithspaces{A Name With Space}

\newwrite\fl%

\def\tempstring{}
\def\createfilewithoutspaceinname#1{%
  \expandarg\StrDel{#1.lst}{ }[\tempstring]
  \typeout{tempstring is \tempstring}
  \immediate\openout\fl=\tempstring
}

\begin{document}


\createfilewithoutspaceinname{\namewithspaces}

\immediate\write\fl{\string Hello World}

\immediate\closeout\fl

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solutions suits me better because actually, I am going to use `\StrSubstitute` to remove all *special* characters from the file name. And, yes, I am do closing the file before creating a new one. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Masroor: You're welcome. Perhaps using `expl3` features it might be even easier to get what you want, but that's another approach to learn.

Answer (score 4):

`xstring` commands mostly do not work by expansion. The latex format includes an expandable command to remove spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}



\def\namewithspaces{A Name With Space}

\makeatletter
\def\createfilewithoutspaceinname#1{%
\typeout{\expandafter\zap@space#1 \@empty}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\createfilewithoutspaceinname{\namewithspaces}

\end{document}
```

causes a message of

```
ANameWithSpace
```

on the console